# Most suitable pushing technique for specific operation

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification, comet, long-polling

I have a website in PHP and I'm trying to implement a push notification system that handles the following:

1) Get data array from some other website's api
2) Check if the data exists in my own mysql database
3) if any of them doesn't, send a new notification to the client including these data
4) else go to step 1

I've used the ajax comet technique to achieve this, but I was wondering if it's going to be too slow when dealing with lets say 500 users doing requests to the database. Is the caching way the one to follow then?

Generally speaking, is there a better approach to my problem than using the comet technique? I am asking for some guidance, not specific implementations.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: webSocket is the modern way to do push to browser clients.

Comment: Cometd already supports Websocket.